# VM Ubuntu 16.04 , No se inicia ningún Navegador web

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

estoy en una maquina virtual ubuntu 16.04, instale ubuntu desktop con vncserver . ahora cuando ingreso por vnc viewer no pueo acceder a ningun navegador, simplemente no se inicia.
Estoy ocupando los servicios de google cloud

Segui estos pasos para instalar desde la terminal

sudo -s

1-apt-get update

2-apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

3-apt-get install gnome-panel gnome-settings-daemon metacity nautilus gnome-terminal vnc4server

4-enable ubuntu firewall port for vnc (ufw allow 5901:5910/tcp)

5-vncserver

6-cp /home/$user/.vnc/xstartup /home/$user/.vnc/xstartup.bak

7-vim /home/$user/.vnc/xstartup

gnome-panel &

gnome-settings-daemon &

metacity &

nautilus &

gnome-terminal &

:wq!

8-reboot

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que tamaño de VM estás usando? yo tuve problemas en una micro pero en la standard me funcionó bien

Comment: @JoséSoní era el standard

Comment: voy a buscar si encuentro los pasos que yo seguí los traduzco y te los paso